# Apex long html in static content

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I created an Apex application and I want to display a html site. I copied the html source inside the the source text of a static content. This works successfully with short code but it seems to be limited with larger content. My question, how can I show a html content inside an Apex application page?

Answer (score 1):

The content of regions is limited to 32K characters.  To overcome this you could split the HTML into chunks each under 32K, and create a region for each. You could use a template like Blank With Attributes to avoid getting borders and titles around each part.

Comment: The html code contains a plot which I think would be hard to split, so is there any other possibility to show the html page or redirect to that page

Comment: Yes, create a region of type URL and under setting specify the location of the page you want to show.  Or create a button that redirects to the URL.

Comment: Can I host the page inside the application?

Comment: No, APEX can only contain APEX pages.

Comment: You could put the html page in an iframe

Comment: The closest you could get to hosting would be to place the static content on the middle tier - near where the /i/ files are located.

Comment: @Scott OK, I see and how and where to reference this in the page?